# how to get POST data value to menu function using ajax& jQuery in drupal

Tags: ajax

jQuery(document).ready( function () {
    jQuery("#edit-suspension").change(function()
        {
             var basepath = Drupal.settings.basePath;
           var key = jQuery(this).val();

```
      //alert(key);
  jQuery.ajax({
           type:'POST',   
           url: basepath+ "custom_menu",
           data : {output:key},
            success:function(data)
            {
                     jQuery('#content').html(data);
              }  
        });
    });
```

how to get the output value in the menu function using $_POST method

Comment: Why you are writing javascript when you can use `#ajax` to your form element?

Comment: yeah but i am trying to do in JavaScript  . And also i got output for this by using $_post; Answer is $_POST['output']